# Resolving a MATLAB class method handle using the method name alone

Tags: oop, matlab, methods, handle

I'm trying to call a method within a class, assuming I only know its name (aka, a char vector with its name)

I tried calling `str2func(['obj.' functionName])` - where functionName is the name of that method, without any luck - I can't seem to grab the handle of the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference it like a field

```
obj.(functionName)
```

or using `feval`

```
feval(functionName, obj, ...)
```

I recommend the first option.

Comment: @AlaShiban : Consider to accept the answer if the answer is a solution for your question. See [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for further details.